# 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento2, php, magento2.4, zend

I am getting this error that I couldn't know from where it is generated

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Front controller reached 100 router match iterations
```

I think it is coming from
.../dix.ml

SimplifiedMagento\RequestFlow\Controller\Page\Router
false
61

If anyone has an idea about this error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to disable that extension and then check, if error resolve or not? Share the code of that controller.

Comment: Some code shared on the blog could help us see the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this threads
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations/td-p/66958